# How to read data from file following a certain syntax in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io, scanf

How do I read the following data into MATLAB matrixes. This following data is stored in a file.

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Point1
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Point2
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Point3
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Point4
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Point5
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Point6
4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,Point7
5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,Point8
4.4,2.9,1.4,0.2,Point9
4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,Point10
5.4,3.7,1.5,0.2,Point11
4.8,3.4,1.6,0.2,Point12
```

Its four float numbers seperated by commas and followed by a string.

I tried to use the following code but it doesn't seem to work properly.

```
fid = fopen("file.txt", 'r');
```

I want to get the four float values in each line into a numberoflines * 4 matrix and the string in each line into a string array.

```
fid = fopen('iris.data');

tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    disp(tline)
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    scanf(tline,'%f,%f,%f,%f,%15c');
end

fclose(fid);
```

I am new to Matlab and I am doing something very wrong here, so please bear with me.

Thanks,
Sagar.

Comment: `fopen("file.txt", 'r');` shouldn't they both be `'` and not with `"`?

Comment: The fopen works fine and I get a valid fid. The problem is I don't know how to read the values now and enter them into matrixes as I mentioned in the original question

Answer (score 2):

try this line:

```
vec = sscanf( tline( 1:end ), '%f,%f,%f,%f,%*s' )
```

should work, regards

Comment: fid = fopen('iris.data');
ImportData = zeros(150,4);
i = 1;
tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    ImportData(i,:) = sscanf( tline( 1:end ), '%f,%f,%f,%f,%*s' );
    disp(ImportData(i,:));
    disp(size(ImportData(i,:)));
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    i = i+1;
end
fclose(fid);

However, the fifth element in each line in the file which is a string, its still not being (read) or copied into the Matrix.If I change ImportData = zeros(150,4); to ImportData = zeros(150,5); I get this error

??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Any help with that? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can't mix datatypes in Matlab. Therefore you are not able to store your string in the same variable. But since your points are numbered ascending, you could store your iterator value i as the 5th element. Don't see the point in storing the string - you can't do anything with this information...

Comment: Yaa, you have a point there. I guess I don't need the string anyway. Thank you :)